# I had my title corrected despite taken it almost verbatim from the "Writing Good Titles" article

Tags: discussion

[Somebody removed a part of the title on my question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28239118/2) despite it being almost identical to an example "good title" from the [article linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648) in the balloon that shows up if you make a bad title:

[image]

(My inspiration was the third one, i.e. "Python: What OS am I running on?")

Of course, they linked to [a different meta discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), seemingly arguing in their favor. So... is the "Writing Good Titles" example wrong, or what? I only wrote my title that way because the format was suggested to me by what seemed an official source.

Comment: Those are definitely not good examples of good and bad examples.

Comment: Tbh, that post is from 2009 and is severely outdated at this point. Fixing it would basically be completely rewriting it, but we already have better information available in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I think just changing the link would be a good solution to this. That FAQ on MSE is not worth reading.

Comment: It seems weird to me that the StackOverflow software itself links there, if it's a rubbish source of information.

Comment: That particular title filter is the oldest filter that exists in the system. They likely forgot that it even links to an old MSE post. I'm certain it will change now that you've brought it up.

Comment: I'm with animuson, that older Meta question is wrong in almost every way from how Stack Overflow actually works. Suggesting grammatically incorrect, broken sentences as titles? Leading with tags in titles? When was that ever preferred here? Why are we using it as a reference for how people should title questions?

Comment: Am I missing something? Isn't that given as an example of a bad title?

Comment: @Bart It was edited moments ago after it was brought up.

Comment: Ah, that would explain it @animuson :D

Comment: @BradLarson adding on to what you said, that post suggests that you do exactly the things that cause the filter to trigger.

Comment: **NEVER** tag in the title, it is just that simple! You copied a **bad example** that put tags in the title.

Comment: I prefer tags in the title because the relevant information is then all in one place and I don't have to search for and interpret the taglist. Sure, highlighted favourites is helpful, but not in the case of a mistagged question. Different people use different methods to locate information, and it's very poor practice to attempt to force **your** preferred operating procedure on others.

Comment: This is the second issue relating to titling/tagging I've seen getting a lot of attention in the last couple of days, and I can't help but feel there's a problem - at least for me, a LARGE percentage of the questions I look at come from the sidebar on the right hand of the screen.  Tags don't appear there, and some question categories are outright forbidden from making sense without tags.  Either tags need to auto-format into the names, or tags SHOULD be part of naming convention, but the latter solution seems totally abandoned by now.

Comment: @DarrenRinger: That's a good point. Perhaps the sidebar needs a slight adjustment, as "no tags in the title" has been the standard for quite a while now (on SO, anyway; can't speak for other sites).

Comment: Good catch, Alex! I suggest a [tag:feature-request] that the link (and possibly the title filtering logic) be updated as they seem to have got out of date.

Comment: @DarrenRinger: I would prefer to see tags in the tooltip in some fashion. Barring that, a de-emphasized display of the primary tag alongside the link name would also work.

Comment: Not sure if this is still on PC, but the mobile web version still links to that broken MSE page

Comment: @animuson (and others) FYI, I just revised that MSE post (as it's a FAQ and a CW post) and replaced those terrible examples with better ones (chosen for their scores and closure statuses).

Answer (score 23):

The [answer you linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10648/272217) contains this item:

> 5. Don't sweat replicating a tag keyword.
>
> The tags are orthogonal to the title. There's a good chance that if a question is about some particular topic, a good title for the question will include the topic name. Glance at the front page and you will see this is quite common.

[Another answer there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10651/159251) goes into more detail on this issue, concluding:

> ...I think it is fine to duplicate the tags in the title, but only when they can be worked into the titles organically and conversationally.

Note that there's even [an automated warning when you do this in an extreme form](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70498/automatic-removal-of-bracketed-tags-from-question-titles). The FAQ that the editor linked to is the definitive document on this issue; tags in titles are **unnecessary** and even unwelcome.

Comment: Not saying Jeff Atwood is the sole arbiter on this issue, but [his opinion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105991/272217) is (was?) that my original title is not objectionable.

Comment: Was... tags in titles dont add value.  No need to detract from the actual problem @Alex.

Comment: @Alex I also dont think that was what Jeff Atwood was saying AT ALL.  He said ... "#1 and #2 are ... not really a problem **so long as they are not happening "too often**". (emphasis mine) And he was speaking about automating their removal.  So, not important enough to automate, but still not needed.  The comments below that post reflect the community opinion more adamantly.

Comment: Tell that to all the Swift/Obj-C question posters

Comment: @nielsbot As far as I can tell the Swift question posters mostly put things like SWFIT in their titles - so, no problem.