# Remove boilerplate words from titles to avoid false matches for similar questions when posting

Tags: discussion, title

I've noticed that a lot of questions (both on SO and Meta), have titles such as:

- How can I do X?
- Is there a way to do X?
- Is it possible to do X?

etc.

Wouldn't it be better to rename them to "Do X"? That will be shorter and avoid words that don't add any information to the question (I'd even consider them as noise). My motivation is removing the false positives. Every time I ask a new question, SO suggests a list of similar questions, and if my question is "How can I do X?", I get a lot of "How can I do Y?", although X and Y aren't related at all.

Comment: Please no. This is hardly one of the most problematic types of noise that we have.

Comment: If anything, making it shorter is certainly not the way to go.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I've added a rationale

Comment: But, shortening the title to 'do x' would increase the number of false positives, not reduce it. Better to provide a small amount of context in the title like 'In X, how do I Y, without resorting to Z?'

Comment: @rene what would you suggest instead?

Comment: @theB how about `Y in X, without Z`, e.g. `cartesian product in haskell without Prelude`?

Comment: @dimid I suggest [Writing a good title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) which is maybe the hardest part of any question.

Comment: @rene my point exactly (4. Don't start with "How do I...")

Comment: Whip the OP until they learn to create the title after they ask the question. Or just downvote and move on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not better to rename them. Nor is it a good to edit the perceived noise out.

[Writing titles is hard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title).Do note that the quality of that FAQ is disputed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285083/had-my-title-corrected-despite-taken-almost-verbatim-from-writing-good-titles) but so is a second [answer on the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/112966/158100), which proves how hard it really is.

For me a title should be the invitation to look at the question and for future visitors it should give them enough info to tell them if the answer they are looking for is in that question and its answers.

Remember that there is already some [word filtering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/110890/158100) on titles but that didn't solve much [pr0blams](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3Aproblam).

I don't think those few words are much of problem in a title as long as they are used to correctly describe the issue in the question. If a title can be improved to better reflect its context please do so, with or without *How can I do*, but don't go on a *remove non-info from titles* edit spree.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not going to edit anything. Judging by the downvotes, no else sees a problem here. Oh well.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with rene that we should no impose a ban on what words can be put in titles.

On the other hand, I think it would be perfectly reasonable to request the title similarity algorithm be tweaked. I suggest that you play around with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) and see if you can make a better algorithm. There are plenty of "filler" words that explain little to nothing about the title that could be ignored:

- I/me/they/you/we/them/it
- of/in/around
- a/an
- these/those/the
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

Editing titles to just remove "is there" and similar fluff text is not something that *need* to be done. Search engines already good at ignoring such text and people can read those variations just fine.

It would be better to close groups of related questions as duplicate of good one rather than editing titles. If they happen to be actually unique questions editing titles to *clarify* problem may be useful.

If you happen to read a post that deserves some edits - feel free to make clarifications/cleanup in title *in addition* to overall post edit.

Note: if you plan to do any bulk modification make sure to get full edit privileges first and get confirmation on META that such change is welcome.