# Why do so many posts contain poor grammar or poorly worded titles?

Tags: discussion, questions, low-quality-posts, asking-questions, grammatical-correction

Often times when I visit the homepage of Stack Overflow, the majority of questions state the problem, have horrible grammar, or are in the format of

> how to xyz.

If the point of the site is to ask questions and get an answer, why is the first question I see on the homepage a statement of a problem (*isotope multi level filtering not working*)? One of them is a command (*Convert array to multidimensional hash*), and the fourth post in is a

> how to

format question that doesn't make any effort into researching the answer (*How to detect is an element in an array is one character long and matches the first character of any element in another array*).'

So, while I understand many question askers may be foreign with English not being their first language, there is no excuse for the massive amounts of these questions on the site.  Just now at the time of this post, 90+% of posts are in this category of not being a question.  How can this be improved upon?  I try to edit as many posts as I can when I have the time, but there is a limit to how many pending edits one can have at a time.

Comment: *"How can this be improved upon?"* The "edit" button. Oh wait, did you mean something else?

Comment: @CodyGray I try to edit as many as I can when I have the time, but there is a limit to how many pending edits that one can have at a time.

Comment: It's not unusual even in a community of majority native English speakers to have titles in the form of a problem statement, let alone Stack Overflow. What grinds my gears more is "Why [subject] [verb] [object]?" and "[subject] not works" but as you said that boils down to most users here not being native English speakers.

Comment: @BoltClock this one hurts

Comment: @Jodast I'm honestly surprised that you're surprised about this. Stack Overflow the company has been consistently lowering the barrier of participation in this site so that it's currently at around sub-basement level, with the inevitable consequence that question quality is at the same level. Instead of wasting your time editing terrible "questions" that should never have been allowed to come into existence, rather just downvote and move on.

Comment: *...that doesn't make any effort into researching the answer...* That's a whole different issue than grammar problems.

Comment: @BSMP this was just to show the correlation between poor titles and poor posts.

Comment: "question-askers may be foreign" - they probably think _you're_ foreign...

Comment: The FAQ actually promotes non-question titles, like dropping initial "How do I".

Comment: The official language of the EU is BAD English. So my think a lot of posts you refer are officially using the correct language.

Comment: Isn't it also a global decline of interest in writing correctly? Language barriers are an important factor, but I see it in my working environment too. People make really glaring mistakes... and don't correct them, or even care about it.

Comment: @Gimby: It is not just writing, but quality in general. One reason is the minimal-effort mindset. And deadlines.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the format "How to X". For that matter, there's nothing wrong with phrasing a title as a command. ("Convert array to multidimensional hash" *is* a bad title, but only due to being vague and, as it happens, not quite matching what that question's body is asking.) You're conflating a couple of specific styles of title with poor grammar and wording, even though those styles are, in and of themselves, completely fine. Indeed, about half of our [top 50 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes&pagesize=50) use "How to ..." or "How do I ..." titles.

Comment: Related: *[Suggested policy change on handling deliberate writing errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375869)*

Comment: Some people struggle to write understandable English, and I think it's strongly correlated with reading skills, but always worse (If I can read at a bad level, my written level will be terrible). Which explains why the related questions are often poor ones as well (if I can't write English well, I probably can't read well either, and thus I struggle to search for or understand documentations / other sources). The cause could be simply cultural / location (poor English education) or personnal (poor education / malfunctioning brain / laziness trait), but the result is the same.

Comment: Aha - I think your issue is that the titles you're pointing to are, grammatically, not questions? That's fine; they don't need to be. A title like "How to foo the bar" is as clear as "How can I foo the bar?". The title "Difference between frobnicate() and fast_frobnicate()" is as clear as "What is the difference between frobnicate() and fast_frobnicate()?". This is no different to how newspaper headlines are typically not full grammatical sentences. Dropping those extra words in titles is often *good*; it avoids the title truncation in Google search results from hiding key parts of the title.

Comment: @IanKemp, you seem to be implying that the bar used to be higher. Stack Overflow has always welcomed ESL contributors, and there have always been low-quality questions (in grammar as well as in content). I don't think the level of quality has changed at all from the beginning. We could look at average question score over time to see if the quality is dropping, improving or staying the same.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/989886/question-scores-over-time Looks like questions are, in fact, getting worse over time! I stand corrected.

Comment: @philipxy Where do you see such advice in the FAQ? In [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the exact opposite advice is given (examples show good titles *include* fragments like "How do I".

Comment: @Welbog That query is not very reliable; it does not account for question age (e.g. older questions get more upvotes as a function of having been around longer), popularity (more popular questions get seen more often and thus have more opportunity to get upvotes), exclude outliers (e.g. the top & bottom 10 or 100 or so questions), or take into consideration actual quality vs the 'popularity' of the question. E.g. questions (especially from >=2010) asking for a library to do something can be incredibly highly upvoted but be blatantly off-topic; most people don't care about SO topic curation.

Comment: Try to write a message with correct grammar in Suomi if you're not Finish, then you will probably understand why posts in English do not always have proper grammar. For similar reasons, if you write in your 2nd, 3rd or even 4th language, then you probably can't be as expressive as in your first language. For example, in French I know I can say how delighted I am in maybe 10 different ways, with subtle understanding on how they differ. If I have to express the same thing in english I'll probably just pick any word that look ok to me. My english is limited and therefore my titles can't be good.

Comment: On the other matter I do not agree on your observation and I feel like most posts do asks real questions. On the other hand I do agree that sometimes people ask questions a bit too prematurely. When that's the case I think the best answer is to kindly suggest how they could have found the answer themselves. For example how to use a debugger or how do you solve problems in general. Also redirect them to good references book/websites on the topic. Sometimes when you are new to a subject it's hard to distinguish good content from bad content. Sometimes you should just guide people.

Comment: @TylerH Googling 'site:stackexchange.com how do i write a good title'... [How do I write a good title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) See the first comment, upvoted 80 times. (Observe also the question's own title.) PS I don't actually think this has much to do with poor posts. It is difficult to write clearly. Add to that naivete. Then sloppiness. Then egocentricity. Then fixation. Then sometimes laziness. Possibly plus of course ESL. However, SE doesn't address this reality well.

Comment: You can't improve it, it can't be improved. You cannot change other people, you can only change yourself. Some people learn by doing, some by asking. If you see "how" in the subject, move on.  Pick your battles.  Grammar? Ironic, in a space where the python speakers don't understand a word the php speakers are saying. Always remember what it was like to learn.

Comment: @philipxy That's a CW answer written by a random user 10 years ago (and I see has the examples have been called out repeatedly under the comments [and elsewhere](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285083/had-my-title-corrected-despite-taken-almost-verbatim-from-writing-good-titles) for being, well, completely wrong...). Thanks for bringing that to my attention; I'll work to fix it right away.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "foreign"? What country are you from? I suspect you are as foreign as any of them.

Comment: @MichaelKay foreign: residing outside of the country in which the website is created OR residing outside of the country in which most of the active community resides.
I am from the USA

Comment: Most of the active community does not reside in the USA, and the website owners go to some lengths to conceal their Americanness - not always very successfully.

Comment: To amplify this, according to https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2018/ just over 20% of the user community is from the US, compared with (for example) 13% from India. I'm sorry to say it, but you can often tell the Americans as the ones who are least aware that they are part of a highly diverse and highly international community.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

> So, while I understand many question-askers may be foreign with English not being their first language, there is no excuse for the massive amounts of these questions on the site.

...You *do* realize that English is only spoken by [about 760 million of the world's *total* population, right?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=total+english+speakers)  Also, there's something [on the order of 3 *billion*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=total+people+on+the+internet) online users across the globe, which implies (scaling for current population sizes and proportions) that there's only [350 million people out there](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=total+people+on+the+internet+*+11%25) which speak English on a regular basis that are online.

To compound things, there are different [dialects of English](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=dialects+of+English) which cause all kinds of localization issues between a person who speaks American English versus someone speaking Indian English.

So um...yeah, I'd say there's at least an *excuse*, which is more borne out of the fact that this site reaches an international audience.  This is a good thing given that we have the ability to reach more software engineers in more parts of the world.

We just have to accept that they don't all speak *our* dialect of English, and that's okay, until...

> Just now at the time of this post, 90+% of posts are in this category of not being a question. How can this be improved upon? I try to edit as many posts as I can when I have the time, but there is a limit to how many pending edits one can have at a time.

So there's two things here:

- If the question *really isn't asking a question*, then that's off-topic and that can be closed irrespective of one's dialect.
- If the question doesn't appear to be in the right shape of an English question, but is *otherwise* fine, then **edit the question into shape**.

I get it, you're one person acting on these questions, but the answer is definitely *not* to be upset that there are people who don't speak or type the same English as you do.

Also - titles are hard.  It's tough to actually write a reasonably good title which conveys clear and concise meaning without forcing the OP to just rely on said title and say, "The title says it all," since that may not fly in future edits by other people.

We're seen around the world.  It's fine for there to be some slight differences in dialect.  Do what you can to tidy up the grammar and make questions better, *if* they're questions worth keeping.

Comment: That's all very good advice, but one should maybe also mention that poor grammar or wording can lower the quality of contributions substantially. People may just move on if they have problems parsing a question instead of improving it. Users should make an effort to make themselves understood, if only to maximize their chances to get a helpful answer to their problems.

Comment: @Trilarion:  Yes, but the other side of that double-edged sword is for people to make an effort to understand others.  You would be *surprised* at the levels of angst we see when someone uses "doubt" in a question.

Comment: @Lundin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-English-based_programming_languages

Comment: @TylerH Yeah sure and there's also Brainf**k and Lolcode. Which have in common with that list that none will ever become mainstream or get used on larger scale. Do you seriously think there are programmers who only study the "national programming language" and know nothing about computers otherwise? If so, I wouldn't call that programming, certainly not engineering.

Comment: @Lundin I was not aware that Stack Overflow was only for mainstream programming languages. If you can point me to where that is laid out in the Help Center/FAQ/Meta, I'd be happy to adjust my guidance to others.

Comment: @TylerH I haven't said that it was, I only said that you can't function as a programmer if you don't know basic English. For example, the language on SO is English. One of the dumber things I had to do when studying programming was to learn all technical terms in my native language. Which meant I had to learn all technical terms twice, because only the English terms make sense to know. I could ask my fellow swede if he had implemented a "kopieringskonstruerare" and he would just get confused. After which I asked if he had implemented a "copy constructor" and then he instantly understood me.

Comment: @Lundin You seem to be dismissing that list of languages as a valid argument because they are non-mainstream. If SO does in fact allow non-mainstream programming languages here (last I checked, it does), then your dismissal is invalid. I agree with you that for popular languages like C, you should know English or you're gonna have a bad time. But I don't agree that you have to know English to program; the link above easily shows that's not true. As a further caveat, I would bet you *someone* has translated the C manual into Chinese or some other widely-spoken foreign language long ago.

Comment: There's no dialect of English that doesn't employ punctuation or capital letters, and no school that teaches an English in that form. This is not a lack of language familiarity, it's a lack of effort combined with various culturally-driven different opinions in how much neatness matters. Plain and simple.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit:  I go back to the whole "make an effort to understand others" point I had earlier.  I don't disagree with you in principle, but if that's the *only* major gripe you have with someone's communication, then there's plenty of room to work with.

Comment: @Makoto I agree with that

Comment: @TylerH I somewhat disagree that you don't need to know English to program.  What language do you know of that has keywords (if, for, define, var, etc...) that aren't rooted in english?

Comment: @Jodast See my link comment above for an entire list of them.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: What you say is largely true, *but* poor punctuation and capitalization are very common online, and a non-native speaker may not understand how those come off. I've seen Indian speakers who use "sir" where an American would never consider it; I assume that they learned this in school, and haven't figured out that it's not always appropriate in the real world. It's only natural that some speakers go the opposite direction, trusting "real world" text *too* much.

Comment: @ruakh That example is a choice of _words_, that comes down to cultural differences - not the same at all.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good answer. Editor here. Just raised my first question on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420623/how-to-encourage-people-to-use-linebreaks-and-periods?noredirect=1#comment928601_420623). And, I agree, editing posts and telling people  about it, so that they can learn, may be the only way out. Both, English and writing are tough.

Answer (score 19):

It's a global site, and we work hard at being inclusive. I know if I were trying to write questions on a site other than English, I'd be floundering, even with translation tools.

This is where we need the community to participate with useful edits. Rather than making trivial edits on old posts, bumping them to the home page, focus up on obvious edits on new posts.

Be mindful that if a post is unsalvageable and you don't have edit privileges, then it's better to just flag to have it closed. It's like painting a room on the Titanic. A waste of time unless the post is edited into being on topic for the site.

Comment: I do 100% agree that people should try to edit questions more, but unfortunately it seems not enough do it.

Comment: @Jodast depends on  what is your treshold for "enough". Maybe your expectations of "English quality" are too high compared to what is feasible ? As a non-native speaker (trying to put as much effort as possible to write properly as my understanding), I always try to refine / reformulate if there is something that is blatantly hurting my eyes or my internal grammar-police soul. But if it's good enough to my international standards (or if the question is unslavageable for other reasons), I'd let it go.

Comment: thanks in advanced for that Yvette

Comment: Bumping to the home page is a non-issue on a high-traffic site like Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9):

Looking at my own questions (I post far more answers than questions) most of them use a title that is not syntactically in the form of a question. Example: "Waiting for a hierarchy of tasks to complete".

When you click on "Ask a Question" you get a form in which the first box is labelled "Title". There may be something deep in Stack Overflow documentation that asks you to write the title in the syntactic form of a question, but the form itself just says "Title". OK, there's some text in very pale grey (almost illegible on my monitor) that says "What is your programming question?", but the thing that stares at you is a label saying "Title".

Looking back at my own questions, I think I tried to devise a title to tell you what it's about, and the "body" is there to tell you what my problem is and what help I need to make progress. I would suggest that is what readers actually need in order to respond: a title showing the general subject area, followed by a detailed statement of the problem and request for help. Neither needs to be grammatically in the form of a question in order to communicate effectively what is needed.

Comment: PS. I am probably a "foreigner" in your eyes. My native language is English, but I have great trouble identifying American fire hydrants in a Captcha. StackOverflow needs to be more international.

Comment: Absolutely; these are the best sort of titles. Their succinctness is an asset for people in answering-mode, as I'm sure you know, and more importantly, in search-mode.