# What more can be done to stop users from constantly creating poorly formatted posts?

Tags: discussion

I'm not going to blast anyone for creating bad posts, but what I will say is that today I've edited almost all of the answers of a certain user who has posted nothing but poorly formatted answers with lots of spelling mistakes and terminology that might come across as self-deprecating or rude.

Most of my edits on their posts have been approved but this person doesn't seem to be stopping and they've even posted another poorly formatted answer right after I edited the last of their posts.

What more can be done to stop users like this from constantly creating poorly formatted posts with spelling mistakes?

Comment: You might remind them about that in a comment.

Comment: It’s within a mod’s remit to warn/suspend users for consistently poor contributions. If you’re satisfied that’s what’s happening, you could raise a custom flag and describe the situation

Comment: Bad grammar or spelling mistakes on otherwise good post is IMHO nothing where a moderator will or should issue a warning. As long as the post is understandable, editing the grammar should solve the problem. Keep in mind that not everyone is a native speaker here.

Comment: @BDL: I don't believe for one second it is due to a lack of ability. Most know perfectly well how it ought to be, but they have the minimum effort attitude.

Comment: @BDL agreed.  I never call anyone out for spelling/grammar issues unless their profile suggests that they're a native speaker (and thus being sloppy/lazy); if it appears that they're from a country with a different primary language or their profile is too minimal to make an assessment I just edit and move on.

Comment: LogicalBranch, do you think your case is where the user does not understand how to format well, or they do understand how to format well and are being wilfully difficult? The latter is more serious, in my view, but I think it is fairly rare - most misspellings or poor grammar or chatty material come from people who do not know any better.

Comment: However if you spot rudeness, flag for a moderator. If you see it consistently, raise a custom flag and explain the pattern you are seeing.

Comment: @halfer To be honest, I'm really don't know if they're doing this on purpose, they just have lots of really bad posts.

Comment: Fair enough. To some degree, I think it matters. That said, there are some posters who choose a wilfully unconventional style and stick to it, and mostly their posts are resistant to edit improvements (as the author will carry on with the same errors and/or rollback). Moderators generally will not help out here, unless the style is sufficiently annoying to warrant many editors getting involved independently.

Comment: "terminology that might come across as self-deprecating" - why is *self-deprecating* terminology something you consider a problem?

Comment: You are talking about me right? i makera good answers yehaaa!

Comment: @BDL Wasn't aware that formatting was a function of native language, and all modern browsers have spell checkers in them.

Comment: I'm more interested in finding out to discourage users from habitually [making silly edits](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22825099)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, that does seem a fairly pointless edit.

Comment: We could disable the "Ask a Question" interface.

Comment: "I've edited almost all of the answers of a certain user": well, don't do that. You are not that persons janitor, there to tidy the mess they leave.

Comment: Is there a specific format for answers?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are actually two categories in your question, and each has a different answer.

> poorly formatted answers with lots of spelling mistakes

While expecting the best effort from users, we can't do anything about that. A fair few of the users on SO are not native English speakers. Mistakes are bound to happen. What we *can* do is edit their posts into better versions of themselves. That's what community editing is all about. Sometimes you may leave a comment under the post mentioning that if the poster was to pay a bit more attention to formatting and spelling, they'd get a better initial reception to their answers. Nothing quite like the gamification of SO to motivate attention to detail. But beyond that, there isn't anything to do IMO.

> terminology that might come across as self-deprecating or rude

That is a different matter. There should be a measure of professional decorum exhibited by users who post on SO. Edit those things away, and if the poster ignores the gentle hints, flag one of their posts for a moderator to give it a look. Be sure to mention only the foul language, and link to a couple of revisions where the poster is misbehaving. Then carry on.

And of course, if there are technical inaccuracies or dangerous suggestions in the post, downvote and carry on.

Comment: "Most of the users on SO are not native English speakers." [citation needed]

Comment: @Braiam - Waddaya know, myself not being a native English speaker made me phrase it in a way that sounds statistically significant; ironic.

Comment: I could hypothesize that most would have made the same mistake, independently being native speakers or not.

Comment: @Braiam - Then you'd need to present *your* data. I can only testify as to why I myself made that particular mistake. Translation from what I *think* in my inner monologue (which is not in English, in case you wondered) often has me misspeaking ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯.

Comment: @Braiam:  [I thought we had established this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380433/1079354) at one point - there's a percentage of people who speak fluent native English out there, and even that is subject to dialect.  If nothing else, StoryTeller was only *barely* hyperbolic on this point.

Comment: To be fair, not being a native speaker isn't much of an excuse here. A lot of issues can be fixed by (a) paying attention to people fixing prior occurrences of said issues (this would apply to things like capitalization and code formatting) and (b) using a spell checker. Of course this can't fix all issues, but it would be a large improvement to what many people post. Both can, to a significant extent, be done regardless of one's English language competence.

Comment: According to the [2019 Developer Survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019?utm_source=so-owned&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=dev-survey-2019&utm_content=launch-blog#geography) most users are not from native English speaking countries.

Comment: I'd like to point out that as a non-native speaker, getting spelling "right" (at least to a level comparable to normal native speakers) is trivially easy using the tools provided with browsers for free, while getting the *tone* right is incredibly hard and there is no tool for this at all. On a personal level, I dislike people more that make lots of spelling mistakes, because that's just lazy, while coming across as rude is just a side effect of not knowing all the intricacies of a foreign language and no amount of "effort" on the posters side will help.

Comment: @nvoigt I agree that spelling errors are trivial to fix but I disagree that no amount of effort will help people avoid coming off as rude.

Answer (score 14):

Simply stop encouraging them.

If this user has learnt that you're just going to tidy up their posts (including retrospectively) for their free internet points then they have no incentive to improve their content.

Only try to improve posts that could have anything of value to offer, ignore formatting those that you'd cast a deletion vote on (if you had the privilege), and imo, there rarely is any need to edit another persons answer (more polite to leave a comment of any inaccuracies so they can be confirmed)

Comment: I'd to a mix with the accepted answers for the non-native part.

Comment: @Walfrat - I didn't fully see the relevance to the non-native part of that answer as formatting is the same in any language

Comment: Actually, just noticed the question mentioned spelling mistakes. Generally I don't really edit them unless the spelling mistake drastically changes what the sentence is trying to portray, otherwise its clear what the author was trying to say

Answer (score 6):

Just down vote the posts for being low quality, and move on. If everyone who could do that did so, the posters of poorly formatted posts would be rate limited and, eventually, questioned banned, which solves the problem.