# When asking, Is it preferable to use "I" even when there is a "we" and the "we" is not a useful or necessary detail?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, etiquette

I sometimes see question posts where the asker refers to a "we" instead of "I", where the "we" is their company or some other unknown group of people they are speaking on behalf of.

I think this presents some problems, which I'll present in increasing order of magnitude.

1. When the "we" is not defined, I think this can be a possible source of temporary confusion <sup><sub>(at least- it is for me)</sub></sup>: Who is the 'we'? Does it include the reader of the question post? Almost certainly not! But that's not an incorrect literal interpretation, and could be the first interpretation taken without explanation of who the "we" is.

   That is- I can see how- in general- the post could be *less* confusing if written with "I" instead of "we".
2. I ***can't*** see how- in general- the post would be *more* confusing if written with "I" instead of "we". From experience, I have no recollection of ever seeing such a post where the fact that the writer is speaking on behalf of a group of people is actually a useful or necessary detail to understand and answer the question. <sup><sub>In such a rare case, then "we" should be kept.</sub></sup>
3. I think the "we" is poor form for Stack Exchange's goal of "re-usability" of the value of Q&A posts. If the asker says that the "we" is referring to their company, or that's supposed to be implied, that's likely not going to be true in the same way from the perspective of future readers, whereas "I" would be (with much higher probability). Wouldn't it be better courtesy to use "I" instead of "we" for the sake of future readers where that same "we" should not be statistically expected to apply?

I realize that this post is verging on [bikeshedding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding), but I think it's worth discussing once.

Is that an accurate analysis of possible issues? Have I *missed* any counterpoints?

For those three listed reasons, could it actually be useful to the community at large and across time to suggest askers to use "I" even when to them (the OP), there is a "we"?

Comment: In all honesty, I don't think it's *verging*, I think it's dead-bang on top of it. How is this possibly relevant to the information in a question or the viability of an answer to that question??

Comment: Using "we" instead of "I" is pretty standard in many writing styles, especially when it is not important that a specific person does something. I wouldn't bat an eye to see "when we run <some command>, we get <some output>".

Comment: As one who frequently uses "we" in my posts (since my questions usually refer to something that I and my team are working on), I don't see anything wrong with using "we" vs "I" in a question. I don't see where or how any confusion would be caused by using one term or the other.

Comment: The "who" that is asking isn't important to solving the problem.

Comment: What’s next, a network-wide opinion on the usage of Oxford commas? This is so far past bikeshedding as to be, frankly, ridiculous

Comment: *"I can't see how- in general- the post would be more confusing if written with "I" instead of "we"."* I can't see how, in general, the post would be any more or less confusing if either was changed for the other. This would be a great example of useless edits.

Comment: Related [Are British/International English terms acceptable? (e.g. 'brackets' instead of 'parentheses')](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252503/1595451)

Comment: I would absolutely support that, @Clive. As you surely know, [commas save lives](https://www.google.com/search?q=commas+save+lives&source=lnms&tbm=isch). In fact, don't we [already have a policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on that? It's covered by the "Proofread before posting!" section.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_we

Answer (score 13):

It should not matter for a question whether it uses "we" or "I".

Good questions are applicable to large number of readers and as result whether "we" includes just author, author + their team or everyone who interacted with the question should result in the same understanding of the problem.

I consider "we vs. I" in this context very similar to formatting styles for code - as long as one can read and understand it's ok to pick either option, if choice makes the question confusing - edit it to clarify. And consequently don't edit to just change between "we" and "I" because you personally like it that way.

Comment: We have decided that my choice does not matter. I can use whatever self-referential pronoun that we like in my post. Although it was brought to our attention that my constantly switching between them within the same post may be confusing.

Answer (score 4):

I think "we" makes perfect sense in this context (although I do use "I" when I ask questions, including artificial canonicals). The natural interpretation is that it refers to *everyone who wishes to solve the same problem* (accomplish the same goal, understand the same strange code behaviour, ...).

On the other hand, in *answers* I prefer that the language is depersonalized as much as possible. Referring to "you" (whether intended as singular or plural, as English happens to use the same word) risks coming across as accusatory or condescending.

Answer (score -6):

Consult your nearest copy of [The Elements of Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Elements_of_Style) and make a reasonable decision when *editing* the post.  It would be a waste of effort to try to commentate that the OP needs to make this change, since there's no guarantee that [they even speak your dialect of English](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380433/1079354) as to be able to absorb or appreciate the advice you're emparting to them.

Comment: I assume this is being roundly downvoted because *The Elements of Style* is hot garbage.

Comment: @CodyGray: It's been almost 15 years since I had to read that book so I'm not up with the times. Is there another book you'd have in mind, if nothing else, to make the pain go away?